# mysql aggregate vs store - micropayments forum

Tags: mysql, database, aggregate-functions

I just launched the world's first micropayments forum... [rudebagel](http://rudebagel.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=8&p=12#p12). I was explaining to a friend how on a user's profile page (ie "Bob") it would be possible to see all the posts that Bob had valued sorted from most valued to least valued.  That's when I realized that my table (user_values) in the MySQL db stores each transaction... so the results might look something like this...

1. "My Awesome Sunset" - $0.25 cents
2. "My Awesome Sunset" - $0.25 cents
3. "My Awesome Sunset" - $0.25 cents
4. "Momentous Monkey" - $0.10 cents
5. "Momentous Monkey" - $0.10 cents

Bob clicked the quarter button three times for the sunset and the dime button twice for the monkey.  Clearly I'd have to aggregate the data.

I'm not a database expert... and my anxiety of complex aggregated/joined tables tempts me to simply create another table that gets updated whenever a transaction is made. Then I could use this table for sorting by value and the other table (user_values) for displaying recent activity.

Here's the page that contains the code for when a coin button is clicked...

[ajax_value.php](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ja_bvTdmf8SDBJX2hTZTFTOGs/view)

My economics is better than my programming.

So should I create another table to store the aggregated info or should I aggregate the user_values table every time the info is requested?  If aggregating is the way to go... what's the query?  Thanks in advance!